# Algorithms to compare 3D signal data from accelerometers

Tags: java, algorithm, machine-learning

I'm working on a project that involves the analysis of motion data, to compare and give a similarity score. I am at the point in my application where I can collect and display data, and now need some algorithmic direction.

---

**Goal:** given two (x,y,z) time series of motion data recorded from the accelerometer, compute a similarity score (real number, eventually 0 to 100) that gives a measure of how similar the motion was, from the recordings.

---

**Examples:** Here are some images from my software, giving an idea of the data I've collected (and my opinions on what their similarity scores should be):

This one should score quite well

[image]

Maybe this should score worse

[image]

Should not score well

[image]

Pretty terrible

[image]

Alright score

[image]

Pretty good

[image]

Not good

[image]

---

**Some ideas:** I have some experience in audio processing and computer vision, so my initial ideas come from there. To start I was thinking of low-pass filtering (q: which LPF? There's a lot.) the signals, then trying dynamic time warping. I would compare x1 to x2, y1 to y2, etc in this way. However, this seems to me to lose important information such as how the x1 series relates to z1, compared to how x2 relates to z2 series.

Another thought I had was doing analysis in the frequency domain, perhaps using [MFCCs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel-frequency_cepstrum). This is a common technique in speech recognition from what I understand.

There's also the approach of "screw it, machine learning." I could store templated gestures and run some sort of magic to make them recognizable. This is not my preference (I'd like to be able to pull this off without requiring tons of training data), but if someone knows of a scheme where you're like "Oh this would  *definitely* work well", then sure.

---

**Software + Implementation:** This project is being done in **Java**, and my data is in the form:

```
float[150] x1;
float[150] y1;
float[150] z1; //note: x2,y2,z2 will be of different length, but similar
```

So it should be pretty easy to work with, if anyone wants to recommend libraries to use based on algorithm suggestions.

---

**Other:** There is the issue of orientation. However, my plan is to take one of the samples as the "reference" and rotate every `x[i],y[i],z[i]` point of the other to match it. Then do the comparison. Current plan for this is using this rotation formula: [Rodrigues' rotation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula) Does this make sense?

---

Comment: Hey, did you get any solution to this problem as i am facing same issues with nearly similar data, but i am doing this on android. I posted some questions and no body is answering them.
I wish you could help me out.

Answer (score 4):

You can calculate the classification accuracy using dynamic time warping with One Nearest Neighbor classifier. Consider you data only has three dimensions, this is a relatively easy problem. Using dynamic time warping is a good direction. Also, you can use Euclidean distance. The advance of Dynamic Time Warping over Euclidean distance will disappear when your dataset is large.

Since there are only 3 axes, there are two methods, either using data from a single axis, or using data from all axes. Since using all axes is more likely to generate errors, I would suggest using data from just a single axis. For example, use data from x axis, calculate the accuracy. Then you do the same thing for data from y and z. In the last, you will get a accuracy matrix. In each row of the matrix, there are classification result for different activities. In each column of the matrix, you will see the classification result for the same activity in different axis. This is the training procedure. In the testing procedure, you can follow the result from the axis that gives the highest accuracy.

Moreover, there is a problem with the above method. It only counts on the result in the prior knowledge (the past training phase), it does not count in the new evidence (the nearest neighbor distance) in the testing phase.

I have a paper in submission talking about how to use both the prior knowledge and the new evidence in multi-dimensional time series classification. It is still under review, so I can not share it with you. Otherwise, I can send you the paper for your reference.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, would you be able to explain me some things in private? Maybe skype? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Very broad question, and I'd personally tag this as language agnostic as it really doesn't seem to be related to Java. That said, there are two major kinds of approaches I would take to this problem. Both of these are based in the frequency domain, as for most applications that is the domain that makes sense, but without knowing more about your application it's a little hard to give great advice.

In general I would suggest looking at the absolute accelerometer vector as opposed to just looking at the x/y/z directions.

1. Normalized Spectrograms: Assuming that these samples are from sample of differing but comparable length, my first approach would be a comparison of the overlap of two normalized spectrograms. (Something as simple as percentage overlap will work, but something like an integral measure might be more accurate.) If you use this approach you might find some of BartoszKP's links helpful
2. Principal Component Analysis (Or some variation thereof): Since what you've effectively got is a very large problem space, being able to determine the principal eigenvectors will give you a good idea of how similar the two data streams are. I would suggest determining the top n principal eigenvalues and then use a simple similarity metric (Cosine similarity comes to mind.) over the space of eigenvectors to figure out how similar they are on the whole.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. How about DTW over cosine similarity? Since the sequences can be shifted or stretched in time, I'd figure the eigenvectors may be as well.

Comment: Also, how about looking for a "motion template" (saved data) in real-time? I was thinking about separating the data into buckets, finding features, and then using a Markov model (I think that's the right term). So if in my real-time data I saw feature-after-feature corresponding to the full template then I'd say I have a match.

Comment: @JDS Between DTW and cosine similarity I might actually recommend cosine over DTW mostly because cosine similarity is much simpler to implement, much faster for large datasets, and actually remains quite robust to stretched vectors since it's actually independent of magnitude. My intuition is that you'd have largely unchanged primary eigen vectors in a shifted or stretched signal, but it depends on your specific application.

Comment: @JDS The motion templates are a pretty good idea, though I imagine it might be tough to accurately segment the data into templates. If you tried some blob-detection and then used PCA or MPCA on those blobs and did a PCA comparison on those it would probably be a good improvement. That said, it depends on your application since I'm not certain what kind of templates you'd be getting here, so it might be more or less useful depending on that.